# How can I connect my SQL Server database that is placed on another server using API or Web Service in MVC to website that is on a different server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, rest, soap, webapi

I uploaded my website to GoDaddy web hosting and the database is placed on another server.

I want to create an API - either REST or SOAP - to connect my web site with my SQL Server database.

I need help - how can I create an API in ASP.NET MVC 5 so that I can connect my database with my web site? Kindly provide me with a link or code so that I can solve my issue.

I have never worked on API before - any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is now old school. Try ASP.NET Core.

You need to design and develop an N-Layered application: Data, Service and UI.

It doesn't matter where the database server is sitting, as long as your WebAPI can connect to it.

I suggest you build a restful web api with asp.net core :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Put your db connection string in the app settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Although you use other database server, it doesn't matter. You just need to make sure you check your connection string and point it to your database server. For publishing method, it is same, you can use FTP or Visual Studio

1. Please open your project with Visual Studio tool
2. On the Solution Explorer windows (which is normally located on the top right hand corner of the VS tool), right click your project and select Publish
3. Please kindly publish it to a local folder, such as C:\Project
4. Please just upload whatever files/folders you see on C:\Project to your server via FTP

If you have any problems, you can contact your support team

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Reference from
[Sample_WebAPI_Project](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-simple-web-api-in-asp-net-mvc/) ,
instead of Using List created you can create Database Connection and get data from Database